# React. this.setState is not a function inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Current component has `state.breaker` value of false. When the scroll event is captured it looks at the `state` and if its `false` it does some stuff.

I would like to have some kind of static delay before the action will recur and that's why inside `goTo` function the `state.breaker` is set to `true` and will block the the further logic of current method for next `2s` until `setTimeout` will return back to `false`.

But at the current moment the following error occurs ***Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function*** when `setState` is called inside `setTimeout`.

```
class Slide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      breaker: false
    }

    this.scrollRedirect = this.scrollRedirect.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.refs.holder.addEventListener('mousewheel', this.scrollRedirect);
  }


  scrollRedirect(e) {

    const path = this.props.location.pathname,
    goTo = (route) => {
      this.setState({breaker: true});
      hashHistory.push(route);

      setTimeout(function () {
        this.setState({breaker: false});
      }, 2000)
    };

    if (!this.state.breaker) {
       ... code that executes goTo on condition
    }
  }

  ... render code

}
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You are loosing context. Use arrow function as simple way to preserve proper execution context:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({breaker: false});
}, 2000)
```

Remember that anonymous function will have context `window` inside, unless you explicitly bind it with [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind). So here is another way to solve this problem:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  this.setState({breaker: false});
}.bind(this), 2000)
```

Comment: true, thank you! :)

Comment: Blessed Arrow Functions :)